# Expectation of inverse of a symmetric matrix with gaussian elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, parameter-estimation

Is there any way to calculate:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \; ( H^{T}H )^{-1}
\end{equation}

assuming that the entries of the matrix $H$ are gaussian random variables with unknown means but same known variances, and $\mathbb{E} $ is the expectation operator.

Thanks in advance